# How can i remove all fragments that are added with the fragmentmanager?

Tags: android, fragment, fragmentmanager

I added multiple fragments like this :

```
 currentWebViewFragment = tabs.get(currentTabIndex);
 FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
 ft.add(R.id.webViewFrame,tabs.get(currentTabIndex));
 ft.commit();
```

But "If an activity is paused or stopped, the system can drop the activity from memory by either asking it to finish, or simply killing its process.

if the activity is destroyed and saves it's state, so does the fragmentmanager.

how can i remove all the fragments that were added from the fragmentmanager when the activity gets destroyed and decides to save it's state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add all the fragments into an `ArrayList`, then you are able to use `remove(fragment)`, for example:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

for (Fragment fragment : fragmentList){

    ft.remove(fragment);

}

ft.commit();
```

You might do it into `onSaveInstanceState` method or into `onStop` if you want to avoid saving state.